# Guard Tower stopped firing in Warcraft 3

Tags: warcraft-3

When I was being attacked today, one of my Guard Towers stopped firing.  It was shooting arrows just fine until it suddenly stopped.  My opponent didn't have DragonHawk riders or Cloud. Is there any way he could have stopped my tower from firing, or could it have been a bug or a hack?

Comment: maybe w/e those hostiles that were attacking it died or moved out of range?

Comment: without a video to see this occuring its almost impossible to answer this question based solely on your current description.